# Alfresco : ldap sync after user login authentication

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

After referring so many forums, I am able to authenticate and sync active directory users to alfresco. The problem is we have more than 25,000 users and rite now we are planning to open alfresco only for selected users. Whenever someone search people they will be finding all the 25,000 users who are not even using alfresco. My It team is not willing to create seperate group for these selected members. Is it possible to sync only users who are logged in.

I am using alfresco 4.2e Binary Installation. Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: How will you determine who's a "selected member" to get Alfresco access, and who isn't?

Comment: Only selected members know the url

Comment: And what happens when someone accidentally shares that URL with a wider group? Security by obscurity isn't generally recommended as an effective protection scheme...

Comment: Yes that a valid point but at present I need they way to stop syncing when alfresco start and sync the users who are logged in alone

Comment: no, there is no OOTB feature for that use case

Comment: I don't have many users in AD, could you give me the code for sync with the AD. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The most easiest way would be to distinct users to sync via LDAP query. 
You could find this [link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/authentication-ldap-sso/alfresco-ldap-control) useful.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont help in my case. All the 25k users are in same container and I need to sync users who are logged rather than syncing everyone

Comment: It could, write different query, don't use container for filtering users :)

Comment: Unfortunately every user belongs to same container named eg: abc and everyone have similar user properties except name and email. How to filter then?

Comment: You need something to distinct users in AD. If I assume correctly - you cannot modify AD users, then you don't have options with custom LDAP query. You'll need another solution

Answer (score 0):

This scenario should do it:

- enable ldap authentication
- configure the authenication chain to include Alfresco and LDAP. This will ensure to try to authenticat against both systems. e.g.

  ```
  authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,ldap-ad1:ldap-ad
  ```

### disable sync

```
# This flag enables use of this LDAP subsystem for user and group
# synchronization. It may be that this subsytem should only be used for
# authentication, in which case this flag should be set to false.
ldap.synchronization.active=false
```

If you start Alfresco the very first time there is no user in Alfresco. Depending on your strategy how to control the user creatioin you could ether:

### create user manual

If you're running on linux the easiest way would be to use the [alfresco-shell-tools](https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-shell-tools/) otherwise you could use the csv-import feature in the user admin. The trick is to use the same username so Alfresco will try to authenticat against both systems before it fails.

### create user on first login

Another way is to enable implicit user creation on first login. This isn't my recommendation since you will get trouble later because the user has no email address configured / no user info is synced. (This way is not tested - if this doesn't work you may define a sync query which doesn't return users to enable sync)

```
synchronization.autoCreatePeopleOnLogin=true
```

you will get the auto-creation of people who were successfully authenticated but weren't brought in by the sync

Comment: yes, but the user data will never be synced. So e.g. a changed email in LDAP will not be sychronized to Alfresco after the user was logged in the 1st time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add/change this line also on ldap-authentication.properties :

```
ldap.authentication.active=true
ldap.synchronization.active=false
ldap.synchronization.autoCreatePeopleOnLogin=false
synchronization.syncOnStartup=false
synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=false
```

and add on alfresco-global.properties :

```
create.missing.people=false
```

Comment: create.missing.people does not exist